# demigod interaction with dragon breath

Tags: dnd-4e

In regards to the demigod (phb) epic paragon path lvl 30 feature...

**Simple Question**
If I am playing a dragonborn fighter and the only encounter attack power I have left is my dragonbreath racial, am I correct in assuming that I could use the dragon breath attack as a minor action and regain a standard action encounter power, use that on the same turn (and subsequently regain my dragon breath power to do the exact same thing on the following turn)?

**Harder Question**
Assume I have the feat "dragon born channeling" (MP2). When I expend the dragon breath racial power to add its damage to a martial encounter attack power? Would I be able to do a similar loop as per the above example? For example, I only have a standard encounter attack power.  I use it, immediately get the dragon breath, and immediately expend it with the dragon born channeling feat, and gain back the standard encounter attack power I just used.

**Hardest Question**
Following the above logic, If I have the fighter encounter attack power "Rain of Blows" (phb), how would that interact with the dragon born channeling feat and the interaction with the lvl 30 demigod feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked up the feature for demigod in the compendium and the most important thing to note is it states the first time you expend your last encounter attack power during an encounter, you regain one encounter attack power of your choice.

The wording actually makes these all these essentially the same answer, this feature only works once during an encounter when you expend your last encounter attack power.

So 
a. After dragonbreath you get an encounter back of your choice, but this feature does not kick in again on any subsequent turns.

b and c. Assuming you use dragonbreath to augment your last encounter attack power, you regain one encounter power after the attack.

Comment: This sounds drastically different than the wording of what is in the PHB.  I don't have access to the compendium so has this had an errata done to it?

Comment: After some hunting, I found it was given errata in the Divine Power handbook and the current wording matches my answer. It notes the change was to prevent recursive action granting powers.

Comment: @Tony If it was errata'd in the Divine Power book, why does the Chosen Epic Path (in the Divine Power Handbook) have the same wording that matches the Demigod Path in the PHB?

Comment: Trying to find my copy of the PHB, I see no errata listed in the compendium, but this is the wording used.

Comment: Here we go. PHB Errata file from WOTC: http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdatePH.pdf p 18 top of column 2. "Page 175: Replace the feature’s text with the following text: “The first time you expend your last 
remaining encounter attack power during an encounter, you regain the use of one encounter attack power 
of your choice.” This change limits recursive attacks 
through action-granting powers, such as trip up, 
follow-up blow, and steal time."

Comment: @silversociety Apologies, the errata appears to have come later to change Divine Miracle in both books for both destinies. Also thanks for the help in locating the change wax eagle.